# Loop-switch sequence antipattern

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I was java SE developer for quite long time but now I'm starting with android. I saw a lot of android projects and I'm interesting why Loop-switch sequence appears in their code so often. I was always trying to avoid it in my code. Is it really so common and necessery approach in programming for android?

Comment: You mean a switch inside a loop? Why do you think this needs to be avoided?

Comment: Perhaps he means [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence), though I haven't seen that in any Android specific code ever.

Comment: I mean ordinary switch-case loop. As I know it's just a derivative of spaghetti code. And very often it's not the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Loop-switch sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) is to be avoided when used to implement a sequence of events. If being used in event driven programming where the events are not known in advance it is necessary and correct to use the construct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the pattern described in [the Wikipedia article "Loop-switch sequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence), then I suspect that what you're seeing in andoid code is the *legitimate* use of a switch-within-a-loop form an event handler as mentioned in the article - usually that would be with a `while` loop.

The antipattern consists of using the construct to model a fixed sequence (i.e. an incrementing  `for` loop), where it serves no point other than obfuscation (and perhaps reintroducing line numbers for those terminally enamoured with C64 BASIC). For an even handler, it is legitimate because the sequence of events is not fixed - you need some way to execute different actions depending on the event type.

However, it is probably not the best possible design - a strategy pattern  would be better OO design (where the different actions consist of different implementations of a methof by the even object itself ore one obtained from it).